# Dataframe to PowerBI's json format

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to convert Dataframe data into PowerBI's JSON format. But no luck so far.

**DataFrame:**

```
  ProductID Name                        Category    IsCompete ManufacturedOn
0 1         Adjustable Race             Components  true      07/30/2014
1 2         LL Crankarm                 Components  false     07/30/2014
2 3         HL Mountain Frame - Silver  Bikes       true      07/30/2019
```

**Expected JSON Format:**

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "ProductID": 1,
      "Name": "Adjustable Race",
      "Category": "Components",
      "IsCompete": true,
      "ManufacturedOn": "07/30/2014"
    },
    {
      "ProductID": 2,
      "Name": "LL Crankarm",
      "Category": "Components",
      "IsCompete": true,
      "ManufacturedOn": "07/30/2014"
    },
    {
      "ProductID": 3,
      "Name": "HL Mountain Frame - Silver",
      "Category": "Bikes",
      "IsCompete": true,
      "ManufacturedOn": "07/30/2014"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use pandas [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method :

```
json = {'rows':df.to_dict('records')}

print(json)

{'rows': [{'ProductID': 1,
   'Name': 'Adjustable Race',
   'Category': 'Components',
   'IsCompete': True,
   'ManufacturedOn': '07/30/2014'},
  {'ProductID': 2,
   'Name': 'LL Crankarm',
   'Category': 'Components',
   'IsCompete': False,
   'ManufacturedOn': '07/30/2014'},
  {'ProductID': 3,
   'Name': 'HL Mountain Frame - Silver',
   'Category': 'Bikes',
   'IsCompete': True,
   'ManufacturedOn': '07/30/2019'}]}
```

Comment: Nice one. I tried `pd.to_json` but the results are orrible [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)